# How can I create a vertical cell list in Excel from a horizontal cell grid?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create an auto-populating vertical list from a horizontal grid. Specifically, as values are entered in the white cells, I want the list below to pull the white cell value, using the gray cell as an index.

[image]

So, using "Chokeland" as the first index, below that name, it would show:

**Chokeland**

Jordan Howard
Doug Baldwin
Marshawn Lynch
.
.
.

Everything I have found will return only one result (VLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH), but I am trying to create a vertical cell list, and can not find any answers.

It should also be noted that the indexed name can appear twice (or more) in the same horizontal row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But this in B46:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$M$28,INT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$M$28)+(COLUMN($B$2:$M$28)/1000))/($B$2:$M$28=B$45),ROW(1:1)))+1,INT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($B$2:$M$28)+(ROW($B$2:$M$28)/1000))/(((ROW($B$2:$M$28)+(COLUMN($B$2:$M$28)/1000))=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$M$28)+(COLUMN($B$2:$M$28)/1000))/($B$2:$M$28=B$45),ROW(1:1)))*($B$2:$M$28=B$45)),1))),"")
```

Copy over and down

Proof will smaller version:

[image]